# Python, comparing parts of a tuple in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So I have a dictionary using tuples as keys, with the first element of the tuple being of the type datetime, and the second part is a string. I want to sort this into a new dictionary, based on whether or not the elements of the datetime falls between a set start and end time. So say I want a dictionary of all keys falling in the datetime range of 2021, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0, and 2021, 11, 17, 23, 59, 59.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
start_t = 2021, 11, 17, 0, 0, 0
stop_t = 2021, 11, 17, 23, 59, 59
New_Dict = {}
    timesorted = sorted(old_dict.keys(), reverse = True)
    for keys in timesorted:
        if keys > start_t and keys < stop_t:
            New_Dict.append[keys]
```

Python doesn't let me compare tuples and datetime. So I was thinking, is there an easy way to then make a new dict, with datetime from old dict, and the same value from old dict? Basically I want an easy way to strip the string part of the tuple in my old dict.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `key` argument of `sorted` to extract the first index of the tuple.
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted